# Xlsread sheet in for loop

Tags: matlab, xlsread

I have a number of excel sheets I would like to cycle through enclosed in a for loop, with sheet name a through A to X. Is this possible?

I tried this:

```
for letter='A':'X'

[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('Grouting_sum_final.xlsx','%s',letter);

% Lots of code  below here (not relevant for the problem)

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, but you do not need the '%s' part of your line.

If you go to [the documentation website](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html), you will find that you have to pass as first argument the excel file name and as second the sheet name.

So your code should read something like:

```
for letter='A':'X'

[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('Grouting_sum_final.xlsx',letter);

% Lots of code  below here (not relevant for the problem)

end
```

Also, I am assuming you are aware that you keep on overwriting your data retrieved from the Excel sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you mean by overwriting data retrieved?

Comment: You are welcome. I mean that for each letter you store the content of the excel sheet into the variables num txt and raw. So, should you need the whole collection, you are not getting it, since once you have finished with one sheet you use the same variables for storing the new retrieved sheet.

So I am assuming you need these variables as input to the further computations not shown, but do not need the whole collection; otherwise you should assign the results to a some data structure (cell array possibly).